# How to use a key from For...Of as an index on the typed object in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

What would be the correct typing for:

```
type Composition = {
  foo: number;
  bar: number;
};

const total = 4;
const composition: Composition = { foo: 3, bar: 1 };

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(composition)) {
  composition[key] = (value / total) * 100;
  // ^--- Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Composition'.
  // ^--- No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Composition'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Ah got it!

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(composition) as [keyof Composition, number][]) {
  composition[key] = (value / total) * 100;
}
```